# circle and scale the texture on 3d model using libGDX on android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I am a new development in libgdx and I do not develop 3D before. I find some problems about 3D model texture.

I import below

[the 3d model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eArC.png)

and I want to draw a picture on the red circle area as shown in the below picture
[the area I want to draw the texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTeRz.png)

So do I need write a shader program? Can anyone tell me how could I implement this texture effect?

edit: sorry for insufficient information, what I want is that draw a picture on to the 3d model front surface in the red circle area, the size is same but the picture is different.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. A 2D overlay over the scene? Or paint the circle onto the model? Does it need to appear at arbitrary places on the model? Is it always a circle of the same size and color?

Comment: @Tenfour04 hello, does my edit have sufficient information?

Comment: Is it the same picture every time you do it?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no, it is football player portrait I want to draw on the model, so it has 11 model with 11 different image on the model

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the model in some 3D modeling software. Split the center geometry (maybe the quad) to have a circular geometry (Triangle Fan). Map the UV coordinates of this circular gheometry to a different texture and save the model. Now simply swap the second texture with each player potrait when rendering the model.
2. Split the center part of the model and render it with a different shader. Use the fragment shader to map the potrait texture onto the model as you need.

Note : Using shaders will be very slow compared to first method.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try it.